Fix permissions for no identity-based policy allows the s3:ListBucket error
I am trying to download files from an S3 bucket but I get this error. Any thoughts on what could be the problem ? I have hidden the exact names and IDs by {xxxxx}. According to the owner, I should have permissions to download the files but not to upload or modify anything.
fatal error: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: User: arn:aws:iam::{xxxxx}:user/{xxxxx} is not authorized to perform: s3:ListBucket on resource: "arn:aws:s3:::{xxxxx}" because no identity-based policy allows the s3:ListBucket 


It means you don't have permission to list the contents of the bucket. What makes you think you should be able to access it?

Thanks !! Well the owner told me I should be able to download it. I guess then there is just some error in permissions. I was just wondering if this was a common error and someone might be able to guess what the reason was.

In my case the role permission action S3:ListBucket had a resource arn:aws:s3:::bucketName/* and it was not working. Removing the /* fix this error.
